# randomly do action with weighted values

Tags: c#, random

lets say I have 5 outcomes

```
Console.WriteLine("1");
Console.WriteLine("2");
Console.WriteLine("3");
Console.WriteLine("4");
Console.WriteLine("5");
```

I want to randomly do one of the above actions using weights so lets say their weights start at 100.

it randomly prints 1 and lowers its weight by 5, making its weight 95.

so after this has done the weights in ascending order are (95, 100, 100, 100, 100) so all the 100 weights have a 5% chance of randomly being chosen over 95 but 95 still has a chance of being randomly picked but not as much as the others.

sample output:(console output)

```
1 (weight = 95)
3 (weight = 95)
1 (weight = 90)
5 (weight = 95)
1 (weight = 85)
2 (weight = 95)
```

Comment: So [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Comment: can you show the output you want? i cant understand

Comment: I just wrote some code to implement your random weighing algorithm and got 1-5 too, so your code must be OK.

Comment: @syedmohsin added sample output but I don't think its going to clear it up much for you.

Comment: @ErikPhilips I have tried nested case statements but I would need to write 625 Lines of code if using nested case statements with random numbers. There must be a more efficient way of doing this

Comment: @PeterJ Could you post this code please?

Comment: Decreasing weights of each selected item will eventually leave all of your items with negative weights.  At what point do you plan on resetting the weights?

Comment: Yes I plan on resetting weights back to 100 after they reach 0 but that's simple enough to implement

Comment: What you're asking for is mathematically the same as having a bag containing 20 each of 5 different coloured balls and removing a single ball at a time. You should just create an array of twenty of each of your numbers, randomly shuffle the list, and then take one number at a time in sequence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a simple code, If I understood well, what you need, you can use this, as a starting point:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<ActionWithChance> list = new List<ActionWithChance>()
                                          {
                                              new ActionWithChance("1", 100),
                                              new ActionWithChance("2", 100),
                                              new ActionWithChance("3", 100),
                                              new ActionWithChance("4", 100),
                                              new ActionWithChance("5", 100)
                                          };

        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            RandomHandler.CreateIntervals(list);
            RandomHandler.GetRandom(list);
        }


    }
}

static class RandomHandler
{
   public static void CreateIntervals(List<ActionWithChance> list)
    {
        int currentBorderMin = 1;
        int currentBorderMax = 0;
        foreach (var actionWithChance in list)
        {
            actionWithChance.TempMin = currentBorderMin;
            actionWithChance.TempMax = currentBorderMax 
                              + actionWithChance.Chance;

            currentBorderMax = actionWithChance.TempMax;
            currentBorderMin = currentBorderMax;
        }
    }

    public static void GetRandom(List<ActionWithChance> list)
    {
        Thread.Sleep(20);
        int allChance = list.Sum(i => i.Chance);
        Random rand = new Random();
        int nextValue = rand.Next(1, allChance + 1);
        ActionWithChance selectedAction = 
list.FirstOrDefault(i => i.TempMin <= nextValue && i.TempMax >= nextValue);

        selectedAction.Chance = selectedAction.Chance > 5 
            ? selectedAction.Chance - 5 : 100;

        selectedAction.DoSomething();
    }
}

class ActionWithChance
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Chance { get; set; }
    public int TempMin { get; set; }
    public int TempMax { get; set; }

    public void DoSomething()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(Name);
    }


    public ActionWithChance(string name, int chance)
    {
        Name = name;
        Chance = chance;
    }
}
```

Comment: Better not to create a new `Random` every iteration. But apart from that, you've coded what I was too lazy to. :-)

Comment: Yeah, I was bored :) But feel free to improve it!

Comment: list.FirstOrDefault and list.sum are not in System.Collections.Generic any ideas?

Comment: System.Linq, since .NET 3,5

Comment: ah ok thanks for some reason it was saying system.collections.generic.

Answer (score 2):

No idea why you would be messing around with nested case statements.

Every time you need to generate a new random number, add up your weights.

Then use [`Random.Next(sumOfWeights)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zd1bc8e5.aspx).

Then compare your returned random number to the first weight, the sum of the first two weights, the sum of the first three weights, etc., until it is less than.

That's your selection. Then reduce that weight by 5.

Comment: You do not have to re-sum your weights each time you generate a new random number.  Just update the previous sum with the same value used to update the individual weight.

Answer (score 0):

Another Approach:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace RandomWeights
{
    public class WeightedItem
    {
        public string Text { get; set; }
        public int Weight { get; set; }

        public WeightedItem(string text, int weight)
        {
            Text = text; 
            Weight = weight;
        }
    }
    public class WeightedOutput
    {
        public static readonly int _decreaseIncrement = 5;
        List<WeightedItem> items = new System.Collections.Generic.List<WeightedItem>();

        public WeightedOutput()
        {
            //initialize the five items with weight = 100
            for (int i = 1; i <= 5; i++)
                items.Add(new WeightedItem(i.ToString(), 100));

            for (int x = 0; x < 50; x++)
                WriteSelected();

            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        public void WriteSelected()
        {
            WeightedItem selectedItem = GetItem();
            if (selectedItem != null)
                Console.WriteLine(selectedItem.Text + ": " + selectedItem.Weight);
            else
                Console.WriteLine("All items have 0 probability of getting selected");
        }

        public WeightedItem GetItem()
        {
            int totalWeight = items.Sum(x=>x.Weight);
            Random rnd = new Random((int)DateTime.Now.Ticks);
            int random = rnd.Next(0, totalWeight);

            WeightedItem selected = null;
            foreach (var item in items)
            {
                if (random < item.Weight && item.Weight > 0)
                {
                    //need a new item and not a reference to get the right weights
                    selected = new WeightedItem(item.Text, item.Weight);
                    //decrease item's weight
                    item.Weight -= _decreaseIncrement;
                    break;
                }

                random -= item.Weight;
            }
            return selected;
        }
    }
}
```